# Windows PowerShell read lines until no lines left

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell that is downloading some XML data over TCP. I need to have all the data written to a file. Each line of the response needs to be written to a new line in the file. The code below only gets the first line. Ignore the extra readline's because the first few lines are garbage data I don't need. How can I continue to write each line of the response until there are none left? Couldn't find anything else on this.

```
$server = "192.168.1.173"
$port = "45678"
$password = "password"

while (1) {
    $tcpConnection = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($server, $port)
    $tcpStream = $tcpConnection.GetStream()
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($tcpStream)
    $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($tcpStream)
    $writer.AutoFlush = $true
    if ($tcpConnection.Connected) {
        $writer.Write("<StageDisplayLogin>");
        $writer.Write($password);
        $writer.WriteLine("</StageDisplayLogin>");
        $ProPresenterData = $reader.ReadLine()
        $ProPresenterData = $reader.ReadLine()
        $ProPresenterData = $reader.ReadLine()
        $ProPresenterData | Out-File -Encoding "UTF8" ProPresenter.xml
        Start-Sleep -m 200
        while ($tcpStream.DataAvailable) {
            $ProPresenterData = $reader.ReadLine()
            Add-content -Path ProPresenter.xml -Value "$ProPresenterData"
        }
    }
    $reader.Close()
    $writer.Close()
    $tcpConnection.Close()
    "Wrote file ProPresenter.xml"
    $ProPresenterData

    Start-Sleep -m 500
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only partially answer your problem. The reason why you only get one line is because of your while loop. There is no **trigger** for it to go back to the beginning and so it does your loop just one time.

With a foreach you can loop through all the lines in your file:

```
 $file = get-content your.xml 

foreach($line in $file){
    $line # this would print each line , one after the other.
}
```

Alternativly you can use a `for-loop` if you can determine the length of the file in advance.

Having said that, is it an option for you to first fully download the file and then write it into a different file?  Or, is it a file that is being constantly renewed with lines added on a certain interval?

Comment: Correct. The data is being constantly updated I believe. I’m not sure how I could download the whole ammount of data to a file. It a TCP request to a server that just get raw data back. So it’s not really a “file” per se. Why wouldn’t the whiledataavailable not work for a loop?